# Call to a member function getIdAluno() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql

need help with some code here

I have a collection of the Classe notas, and i'm getting the information from the database useing this code:

```
$this->notas = new Collection();
    $this->carregaArray();

public function carregaArray(){
$link = mysql_connect('localhost:3307', 'root', 'usbw');
$l = mysql_select_db('estagio', $link);
$sql = "Select * From notas";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$link);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $this->notas->addItem($row);
    }
        }
```

I'm trying to use the $this->notas on this method:

```
public function procurarNota($idAluno,$idElemento){
        if(!($this->notas->isEmpty())){
            foreach($this->notas->getAll() as $nota){
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $this->notas->getLength(); $i++){
                if($this->notas->getItem($i)->getIdAluno() && $this->notas->getItem($i)->getIdComp() == $idElemento){
                    return $nota;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

But it's giving me this error:

```
Call to a member function getIdAluno() on a non-object in D:\8.5\root\classes\UC.php on line 709
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Cheers

Comment: `$this->notas->getItem($i)` is not returning an object, therefore, it isn't possible to get the student ID. Check the implementation of this method.

Comment: 'code' public function getItem($key) {
        if (isset($this->items[$key])) {
            return $this->items[$key];
        } else {
            throw new KeyInvalidException("No match found for $key.");
        }
    }

It's the impementation of the method

Comment: `What am i doing wrong ?` You want the short or the long version? Short: A lot! Long: Deprecated `mysql_*`, badly formatted code, `$this->notas->getItem($i)` seems not to be an object, but without the code for the object in question, we can't be sure.

Comment: Well, if `$this->items` is an array of objects, as I imagine it is, probably the key passed to it isn't being found, thus returning null and throwing the exception. Try putting a `var_dump($this->items[$key])` and check if the result is an object before returning it.

Comment: And, please, for everything in the world, **don't use the deprecated and removed (in last version) `mysql_*`** functions.

Comment: ok thanks for all of your answers, the `var_dump($this->items[$key])`   returns a object.

Comment: I've changed the return to `return (object)$this->items[$key];`and now is giving me this error: `Call to undefined method stdClass::getNota() ` in the class Notas i have this method: `ublic function __construct($idAluno, $idComp, $nota, $final) {
        $this->idAluno = $idAluno;
        $this->idComp = $idComp;
        $this->nota= $nota;
        $this->isFinal = $final;
    }
    
    public function getIdAluno() {
        return $this->idAluno;
    }`